# Rounding numbers: Java's 'Math.rint' in Python

Tags: java, python, math

Does an analogue to Java's `Math.rint` exist in Python?
If not, how can I achieve the same result?

Comment: Do you really need the special behavior of `Math.rint()` instead of `Math.round()`?  `Math.rint(2.5)` is 2, whereas `Math.round(2.5)` is 3.  If not, use the built-in `round()` in Python.

Comment: Yes, I would like an exact replacement...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an exact workalike for `rint` for Python 2:

```
def rint(num):
    """Rounds toward the even number if equidistant"""
    return round(num + (num % 2 - 1 if (num % 1 == 0.5) else 0))

print rint(-1.4) == -1.0
print rint(-1.5) == rint(-2.0) == rint(-2.5) == -2.0
print rint(1.4) == 1.0
print rint(1.5) == rint(2.0) == rint(2.5) == 2.0
```

In Python 3, `round` [rounds toward even](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins) just like `rint` (thanks @lvc), but on Python 2:

> [`round(x[, n])`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#round)
>
> Return the floating point value `x` rounded to `n` digits after the decimal point. If `n` is omitted, it defaults to zero. The result is a floating point number. Values are rounded to the closest multiple of 10 to the power minus `n`; if two multiples are equally close, **rounding is done away from 0** (so. for example, `round(0.5)` is `1.0` and `round(-0.5)` is `-1.0`).
>
> **Note**
>
> The behavior of `round()` for floats can be surprising: for example, `round(2.675, 2)` gives `2.67` instead of the expected `2.68`. This is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can’t be represented exactly as a float. See [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues) for more information.

Comment: `round()` does not do the same as Java's `Math.rint`: `Math.rint(2.5) = 2.0`, `round(2.5) = 3.0`.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer Yes, that's why I highlighed the differences in the quote from the docs.

Comment: You quoted Python docs to explain what `round()` does (in fact, this is the same as Java's `Math.round()`, except that it returns float, not int).  But the OP is looking for a direct replacement for `Math.rint()`, which `round` is not.  Strictly speaking, this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer OK, I added a workalike. "analogue" doesn't mean exact copy, so I assumed he just wanted Python's rounding function when I first posted the answer.

Comment: Yes, agf you're right: I should have used "identical" instead of "analogue".

Comment: @agf -- I assumed that the OP knows about `Math.round` and `round`, but was looking specifically for an exact equivalent of `Math.rint`.  Otherwise this question would not deserve an answer, anyway!  With your updated answer, I took back my -1. ;)

Comment: Its worth noting that in Py3, `round` now uses the same rounding convention as `Math.rint` (ie, ties round to even) - http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in function `round`:

- `round(3.5)` gives `4.0`
- `round(3.4)` gives `3.0`
- `round(3.6)` gives `4.0`

Comment: Not a very complete example. Doesn't explain that rounding is away from zero rather than just towards the even number (which is what the Java version he mentions does, so it's important to point out) or upwards.

Comment: `round()` does not do the same as Java's `Math.rint`: `Math.rint(2.5) = 2.0`, `round(2.5) = 3.0`.